# Error with Equation parsing (java)

Tags: java, equation

I have this code:

```
public class Parse {
    static double eval(String exp) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String stringResult = null;
        try {
            ArrayList<Variable> vars = askForVars(parse1(exp));
            ArrayList<String> usednames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Variable v : vars) {
                if (!usednames.contains(v.name)) {
                    stringResult = replaceString(exp, v.name, "" + v.valueUsed);
                    usednames.add(v.name);
                }
                return Double.parseDouble(engine.eval(stringResult.toString())
                        .toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    static ArrayList<Variable> parse1(String exp) {
        ArrayList<Variable> variables = new ArrayList<Variable>();
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String stringResult;
        try {
            stringResult = exp;
            for (Character c : stringResult.toCharArray()) {
                if (c.isLetter(c)) {
                    variables.add(new Variable(c.toString(), 1.0));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return variables;
    }

    static ArrayList<Variable> askForVars(ArrayList<Variable> as) {
        ArrayList<Variable> result = new ArrayList<Variable>();
        ArrayList<String> usednames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Variable v : as) {
            if (!usednames.contains(v.name)) {
                System.out.print("Value of " + v.name + ": ");
                Double input = Double.parseDouble(MessageUtil.getInput());
                result.add(new Variable(v.name, input));
                usednames.add(v.name);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static String replaceString(String s, String from, String to) {
        return s.replaceAll(from, to);
    }
}
```

It is OK when I have just one variable (EG: 2x, 3x+2x or so on) But my problem comes when I use more than one (EG: x+y, 3x-3y, or so on).

This is the error:

> Value of x: 3 Value of y: 4 javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "y" is not defined. (#1) in  at line number 1 at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:156) at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:170) at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247) at com.company.Parse.eval(Parse.java:24) at com.company.MessageUtil.createExp(MessageUtil.java:97) at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:28) x+y Resolves to: 0.0

Comment: what exactly is happening with the more complex ones?

Comment: `Value of x: 3
Value of y: 4
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "y" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
 at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:156)
 at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:170)
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
 at com.company.Parse.eval(Parse.java:24)
 at com.company.MessageUtil.createExp(MessageUtil.java:97)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:28)
x+y  Resolves to: 0.0`